# Are these 2 paths homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $a,b$ be points in $X$. Let $f,g$ be paths of length $1$ from $a$ to $b$ such that $Im \,f=Im  \,g$.

Does it follow that $f,g$ are homotopic ?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by length of path in an arbitrary topological space?

Comment: @Nizma  I  was using the terminology of my book. Let $p:[0,q]\rightarrow X$ be a continuous function. We say that the length of $p$ is $q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't true. Let $X = S^1$, $a=b=1$. Take $f(t) = e^{2 i \pi t}$, $g(t) = e^{4 i \pi t}$. Then $f(0)=f(1)=g(0)=g(1)=1$, $Im \,f = Im \, g = S^1$. They aren't homotopic if we consider homotopy with fixed ends.

Comment: It is possible that you are using different definitions. I felt this because you asked me about the defintion of a length of a path

Comment: According to my book, the 2 paths you gave are homotopic

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are both of length $1$. What is the homotopy then?

Comment: OK wait. May be I am wrong

Comment: @Nizma Yes I was wrong. Thank you. +1

Comment: I did not ask the question that was really in my head. What if we added the hypothesis that $f,g$ are injective on $(0,1)$

Comment: Hm, we can think about $F(s,t) = g(st+(1-s)g^{-1} \circ f(t))$, will this thing be continuous? In general, not